# Alarm not working in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I get stuck with something that , I guess , is very trivial. 
Basically I am scheduling alarm for a given moment in the future :

```
Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class); 
PendingIntent theappIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Main.this, 0,contentIntent, 0); 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month, day, hour,minute); 
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), theappIntent);
```

works fine while mobile is constantly on. 
My problem is that alarm is not triggered after mobile is restarted
and is TURNED ON on the expected time. 
Is there something I missed? Should I do some extra work to keep alarm
scheduled after restart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reset the alarm when device get boot.
You are missing to detect the app when device boot and reset the alarm..so below is code written in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Also  create a BroadcastReceiver to receive the boot completed intent

```
 public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


 Context ct;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {
    ct=context;
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
    {
      // Reset your alarm here
      Intent contentIntent = new Intent(ct, AlarmReceiver.class); 
      PendingIntent theappIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ct, 0,contentIntent, 0); 
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.set(year, month, day, hour,minute); 
      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ct.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), theappIntent); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Itz ok ..Just add an broadcast receiver in your project file. it will work fine

Comment: @sachi You can do it with broadcast receiver easily so why to use service??

Comment: I have added broadcast reciever also. I will put my broad cast code here check it.

Comment: ITs ok to create service for alarms but you create a BroadcastReceiver which detect when device boots and again have create alarm

Comment: check this my broadcast reciever code here.package org.menthatech.medtracker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
        
       
         Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
            context.startService(startServiceIntent);
            Toast.makeText(context, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
  
}

Comment: @Maneesh please check the code . when i turn on my phone now i am getting force close exception.

Comment: you have to provide values year, month, day, hour,minute in calendar.set(year, month, day, hour,minute); in Broadcastreciver

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5129/discussion-between-sachi-and-maneesh)

Answer (score 0):

You should add an receiver For listening android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED and start your alarm from there.